# PHP - Creating a singleton messaging class used for gathering and displaying errors

Tags: php, singleton

I'm looking for a syntactical win here... I want to be able to add messages into a singleton class to be retrieved later.

Currently it looks like this:

```
class messenger
{
    static $messages;

    public function addMessage( $message ) {
        self::messages[] = $message;
    }

    public function showMessages() {
        foreach ( self::messages as $message ) {
            echo "<p>$message</p>";
        }
    }

}
```

Now I want to be able to use it like this:

```
messenger::addMessage( 'This is a potential message!' );
messenger::addMessage( 'Another potential message!' );
messenger::showMessages();
```

Which would output this ([p] == an html paragraph tag):

```
[p]This is a potential message![/p]
[p]Anotherpotential message![/p]
```

Am I off base with the concept? I really don't want to have to re-associate it with a variable in each different class it's used in, but I'm not sure if my hang-up is "how to do it" or if it's simply not possible.

The concept is to be able to add error messages into this (like an array) that I don't have to globalize and can retrieve later.

**EDIT:** I'm doing this so that through my framework, I can add messages to this class from other classes that might also want to display errors at a later time without having to use globals or re-instantiate the class.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to hide its state from the outside, so:

```
static $messages;
```

Should be:

```
private static $messages = array();
```

Also note the initialization to make sure it's an array before you add messages into it.

Furthermore, the methods you're using should be declared as `static`, otherwise PHP will complain about this (triggering `E_STRICT` warnings), e.g.

```
public static function yourFunction() { }
```

Comment: I made your changes to my file. Now I'm getting an error that says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in messenger.class.php on line 8" Line 8: self::messages[] = $message;

Comment: It should be `self::$messages` not `self::messages`

Comment: Jack - you are the man! I don't typically work without an instance of a class so this is new territory for me. Works perfectly now; Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on what you are asking. Yes, what you are suggesting would work fine. But if you aren't aware, your syntax is a bit off.

```
public static function addMessage( $message ) { ... }
public static function showMessages() { ... }
```